# ANGULAR Input allows comma, dot and number

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, input, numbers

I am working on a project using angular and my task is to create a input for typing price of flight. so this is the description:

- the input must only accept numbers from 0 to 9, comma and dot and have maximum 2 decimal places
- when input is larger than 1000 and then automatically add commas to divisible by 3 index, ex: 1222344546.01 -> 1,222,344,546.01
- example:

  - 000123456.1 -> 123,456.1 -> valid
  - 12344546.01 -> 12,344,546.01 -> valid
  - 0 -> valid
  - 00000.1 -> 0.1 -> valid
  - 00.01 -> 0.01 -> valid
  - .01 -> 0.01 -> valid
  - .001 -> 0.001 -> invalid
  - 000.001 -> 0.001 -> invalid
  - ,01 -> invalid
  - 1231321,1231 -> invalid

I did try with ngModelChange and replace text a little bit with method filterContent but the text still not change anything:

*example.component.html*

```
  <form>
    <input type="text" matInput [(ngModel)]="content" name="content" (ngModelChange)="filterContent($event)" />
  </form>
```

*example.component.ts*

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
import { DialogData } from 'src/app/model/dialog-data';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: './example-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example-dialog.component.scss']
})

export class ExampleDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  content: string = '';

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ExampleDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  filterContent($event: string) {
    const replaceText = $event.replace('a', '');
    this.content = replaceText
  }
}
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "mock-internal-ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^12.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.16",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^0.1.4",
    "@iplab/ngx-file-upload": "^2.0.9",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.2",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.6",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.12",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "flatpickr": "^4.6.9",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-zorro-antd": "^7.5.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.3.0",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "rxjs": "6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.3.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.10",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.16",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.18",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.4",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "all"
  }
}
```

thank for your time and help, it does mean a lot to me. Once again, thank you and have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `(ngModelChange)`, use `(input)` - that will trigger the update

Answer (score -1):

If you are using double way binding, it may cause the content is not updating with ngModelChange. Try to use single way binding, in input tag:

```
[ngModel]="name" (ngModelChange)="filterContent($event)"
```

or

```
[value]="name" (input)="filterContent($event)"
```